# How to do an INSERT with VALUES in Databricks into a Table

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a simple table with the following columns

```
ID int
DESC nvarchar(255)
```

This table is mapped via JDBC as a table in Databricks. I want to do insert like in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

I have found the following example in the Databricks documentation but i dont have a partition i have columns.

```
-- Appends two rows into the partition (p1 = 3, p2 = 4)
INSERT INTO data_source_tab1 PARTITION (p1 = 3, p2 = 4)
  SELECT id FROM RANGE(1, 3)
```

How can i do this in `Azure Databricks`?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it by using the following command:

```
%sql
INSERT INTO TABLE tempSQLSimpleTable2 VALUES ('Hi', 2)
```

Usage: `INSERT INTO TABLE tempSQLSimpleTable2 VALUES ([value_column_1], [value_column_2], ...)`

Only the column data is provided in the order of the columns, not the columns names.

This works for me, but if i should be wrong with my above statement that you have to insert for all columns than please comment or correct.